# An example of non uniform convergence.

Tags: power-series, uniform-convergence

$(a_n)$ is a positive decreasing sequence that converges to $0$, we claim that $\sum a_n z^n$ converges uniformly on $U=\{z \in \mathbb C, |z| \lt 1 \text{ and } |z-1| \lt 1\}$. I don't think this is true and I suspect the condition $|z-1| \lt 1$ is the issue, but I can't prove it, I see that if $z \to 1$ and $a_n = {1 \over n}$ for example the series "blows off to infinity" (?). 
The series converges pointwise, so summation by parts on the rest translates to: 
$$|R_n(z)|=|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1-z^{k+1}}{1-z}(a_k-a_{k+1})|$$
I wasn't able to either prove or disprove the claim using this, what did I miss?

Comment: The convergence is uniform on $U$ if and only if the convergence is uniform on $\overline{U}$, if and only if $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, if and only if the power series converges absolutely on the closed unit disk (because the $a_n$ are positive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. On $U$, that power series converges to $-\log(1-z)$ (here, $\log$ is the main branch of the logarithm). But that function is unbounded on $U$ ($\lim_{z\to1}\bigl\lvert-\log(1-z)\bigr\rvert=\infty$) and therefore it cannot be the uniform limit of a sequence of functions each of which is bounded on $U$.

Comment: Can you please clarify how would I write the fact that it is unbounded precisely?

Comment: The restriction of the main branch of the logarithm to $(0,\infty)$ is the usual logarithm. And $\lim_{x\to0^+}\log x=-\infty$.